# Obtain basic statistics (min, mean, max, sd) using dplyr?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, statistics

I have a basic dataframe:

```
a = c(1,4,3,5)
b = c(3,6,3,11)

mydata = data.frame(a,b)
```

I would like to obtain the same dataframe (two columns a and b), but the basic statistics as lines.

Is there a dplyr command for this?

Comment: Would this suffice? `do.call(cbind, lapply(mydata, summary))`

Comment: @Sotos isn't ```do.call(cbind, lapply(...)``` basically same as `sapply`?

Comment: @M-- Yes it is. Why I used `do.call(lapply...`? No idea :)

Comment: Several solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34594641/5325862) that would just require transposing. Several in base R [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20997380/5325862).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It may be better to have the data in 'long' format and then do the summary

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
mydata  %>%
      pivot_longer(everything()) %>%
      group_by(name) %>%
       summarise_at(vars(value), list(Min = min, Mean = mean, Max = max, Sd = sd))
# A tibble: 2 x 5
#  name    Min  Mean   Max    Sd
#  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1 a         1  3.25     5  1.71
#2 b         3  5.75    11  3.77
```

Comment: Reshaping is a good approach, but I think the OP wants it transposed back so a & b are the columns

Answer (score 3):

We can use `sapply`:

```r
sapply(mydata, summary)

#>            a     b
#> Min.    1.00  3.00
#> 1st Qu. 2.50  3.00
#> Median  3.50  4.50
#> Mean    3.25  5.75
#> 3rd Qu. 4.25  7.25
#> Max.    5.00 11.00
```

or if you don't want the quartiles:

```r
sapply(mydata, function(x) list(Min = min(x), Mean = mean(x), 
                                Max = max(x), Sd = sd(x)))
```

A `tidyverse` solution would be possible using `purrr::map`:

```r
library(purrr)

mydata %>% 
    map(~summary(.)) %>% 
    rbind.data.frame
```