# Creating a versatile descriptives table using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, summary

I'm trying to create a simple code that I can reuse over and over (with minimal adjustments) to be able to print a table of summary statistics.

A reproducible example creates a table with M and SD for the variable `V1` broken down by group:

```
data <- as.data.frame(cbind(1:100, sample(1:2), rnorm(100), rnorm(100)))
names(data) <- c("ID", "Group", "V1", "V2")


library(dplyr)
descriptives <- data %>% group_by(Group) %>%
  summarize(
    Mean = mean(V2)
    , SD = sd(V2)
  )

descriptives
```

I'd like to modify this function so that it will compute M and SD for all variables in my dataset.

I'd like to be able to replace the call to `V1` with something like `vars` which is just a list of all the variables in my dataset; in this example, V1 and V2. But usually I have like 100 variables.
The reason I'd like it to work this way is so that I can do something very easy like:

```
vars <- names(data[3:4])
```

and very quickly select the columns for which I want summary statistics.

A few things for my wishlist:

M and SD for a given variable should be next to eachother and I'd like to add a column above each pair with the variable name.

I'd like the end product to look something like

[image: this example table]

I'd like to use dplyr, but I'm open to other options.
I'd also like to learn how I could switch the rows and columns of the table so that the variables are on separate rows and each group has a column (or two columns, one for M and one for SD). Like this:
[image: another example table]

Close, but no cigar:

1. The newish summarise(across()) kind of helps:

```
dplyr::group_by(df, Group) %>% 
  dplyr::summarise(dplyr::across(.cols = c(V1, V2), .fns = c(mean, sd)))
```

But I don't know how to scale it without making multiple table and using `rbind()` to stack them.

2. I really like the format of `table1()` ([vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/table1/vignettes/table1-examples.html)), but from what I can tell I can only stratify the column M/SDs by another variable. I really wish I could just add additional grouping variables on.

Comment: https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/summarise_all.html

Comment: You can use `data %>% group_by(Group) %>% summarise_at(vars(vars), list(Mean = mean, SD = sd))`

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34594641/dplyr-summary-table-for-multiple-variables/46786941

Comment: @iod but this doesn't put the M and SD columns next to eachother for each variable. I'd then have to rearrange all the variables. Do you know of a quicker way to do this?

Comment: @akrun this also doesn't put the M and SD columns next to eachother for each variable. I'd then have to rearrange all the variables. I'm not opposed, but when I have several hundred variables I need a way to rearrange them faster and add headers with variable names.

Comment: @Jakub.Novotny Sorry, but this is not a duplicate. I reviewed many posts (including the one you linked) and none of them solve the specific issue I'm having.

Comment: @socialresearcher the gtsummary package might help! answer below

Answer (score 4):

There is a limitation in the ordering, but if we use `select`, then can reorder on the substring on the column names

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
data %>%
    group_by(Group) %>% 
    summarise_at(vars(vars), list(Mean = mean, SD = sd)) %>% 
    select(Group, order(str_remove(names(.)[-1], "_.*")) + 1)
# A tibble: 2 x 5
#  Group V1_Mean V1_SD  V2_Mean V2_SD
#  <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1   0.165 0.915  0.146   1.16 
#2     2   0.308 1.31  -0.00711 0.854
```

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68521013/summarising-multiple-variables-without-iteration), and got some really useful and simple answers using `tidyverse`. In the end a really robust approach was made, which I wrapped in a `function` and use regularly.

```
library(tidyverse)

baseline_table <- function(data, variables, grouping_var) {
        
        
        data %>% 
                group_by(!!sym(grouping_var)) %>% 
                summarise(
                        across(
                                all_of(variables),
                                ~ paste0(mean(.) %>% round(2), "(±", sd(.) %>% round(2), ")")
                        )
                ) %>% pivot_longer(
                        cols = -grouping_var,
                        names_to = "variable"
                ) %>% pivot_wider(
                        names_from = grouping_var
                )
        
        
        
}
```

It takes three `arguments`, `data`, `variables` and the `grouping_var` - all of which are rather self explanatory.

Here is a test using `mtcars` with a `2 level` and `3 level` grouping var.

```
baseline_table(
        data = mtcars,
        variables = c("mpg", "hp"),
        grouping_var = "am"
)
```

```
# A tibble: 2 x 3
  variable `0`            `1`           
  <chr>    <chr>          <chr>         
1 mpg      17.15(±3.83)   24.39(±6.17)  
2 hp       160.26(±53.91) 126.85(±84.06)
```

---

```
baseline_table(
        data = mtcars,
        variables = c("mpg", "hp"),
        grouping_var = "cyl"
)
```

```
# A tibble: 2 x 4
  variable `4`           `6`            `8`           
  <chr>    <chr>         <chr>          <chr>         
1 mpg      26.66(±4.51)  19.74(±1.45)   15.1(±2.56)   
2 hp       82.64(±20.93) 122.29(±24.26) 209.21(±50.98)
```

It works out of the box, and are applicable to all `data`, below I used `iris`,

```
baseline_table(
        data = iris,
        variables = c("Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width"),
        grouping_var = "Species"
)
```

```
# A tibble: 2 x 4
  variable     setosa      versicolor  virginica  
  <chr>        <chr>       <chr>       <chr>      
1 Sepal.Length 5.01(±0.35) 5.94(±0.52) 6.59(±0.64)
2 Sepal.Width  3.43(±0.38) 2.77(±0.31) 2.97(±0.32)
```

Of course; some `grouping variables` are not directly suited for this. Namely `cyl` but it does serve as a good example though. but you can recode your `grouping variables` accordingly,

```
baseline_table(
        data = mtcars %>% mutate(cyl = paste(cyl, "Cylinders", sep = " ")),
        variables = c("mpg", "hp"),
        grouping_var = "cyl"
)
```

```
# A tibble: 2 x 4
  variable `4 Cylinders` `6 Cylinders`  `8 Cylinders` 
  <chr>    <chr>         <chr>          <chr>         
1 mpg      26.66(±4.51)  19.74(±1.45)   15.1(±2.56)   
2 hp       82.64(±20.93) 122.29(±24.26) 209.21(±50.98)
```

You can also modify the function to include descriptive strings, about the `values`,

```
baseline_table <- function(data, variables, grouping_var) {
        
        # Generate the table; 
        tmpTable <- data %>% 
                group_by(!!sym(grouping_var)) %>% 
                summarise(
                        across(
                                all_of(variables),
                                ~ paste0(mean(.) %>% round(2), "(±", sd(.) %>% round(2), ")")
                        )
                ) %>% pivot_longer(
                        cols = -grouping_var,
                        names_to = "variable"
                ) %>% pivot_wider(
                        names_from = grouping_var
                )
        
        # Generate Descriptives dynamically
        tmpDesc <- tmpTable[1,] %>% mutate(
                across(.fns = ~ paste("Mean (±SD)"))
        ) %>% mutate(
                variable = ""
        )
        
        
        bind_rows(
                tmpDesc,
                tmpTable
        )
        
        
        
}
```

Granted, this extension is a bit awkward - but it is nonetheless still robust. The `output` is,

```
# A tibble: 3 x 4
  variable `4 Cylinders` `6 Cylinders`  `8 Cylinders` 
  <chr>    <chr>         <chr>          <chr>         
1 ""       Mean (±SD)    Mean (±SD)     Mean (±SD)    
2 "mpg"    26.66(±4.51)  19.74(±1.45)   15.1(±2.56)   
3 "hp"     82.64(±20.93) 122.29(±24.26) 209.21(±50.98)
```

**Update:** Ive rewritten the `function` for added flexibility as noted in the comments.

```
library(tidyverse)

baseline_table <- function(data, variables, grouping_var) {

        data %>% 
                group_by(!!!syms(grouping_var)) %>% 
                summarise(
                        across(
                                all_of(variables),
                                ~ paste0(mean(.) %>% round(2), "(±", sd(.) %>% round(2), ")")
                        )
                ) %>% unite(
                        "grouping",
                        all_of(grouping_var)
                ) %>% pivot_longer(
                        cols = -"grouping",
                        names_to = "variables"
                ) %>% pivot_wider(
                        names_from = "grouping"
                )
}
```

It works in the same way, and outputs the same, unless there is more than one `grouping_var`,

```
baseline_table(
        mtcars,
        variables = c("hp", "mpg"),
        grouping_var = c("am", "cyl")
)
```

```
# A tibble: 2 x 7
  variables `0_4`         `0_6`         `0_8`          `1_4`         `1_6`          `1_8`       
  <chr>     <chr>         <chr>         <chr>          <chr>         <chr>          <chr>       
1 hp        84.67(±19.66) 115.25(±9.18) 194.17(±33.36) 81.88(±22.66) 131.67(±37.53) 299.5(±50.2)
2 mpg       22.9(±1.45)   19.12(±1.63)  15.05(±2.77)   28.08(±4.48)  20.57(±0.75)   15.4(±0.57)
```

In the updated `function` I used `unite` with a default `seperator`. Clearly, you can modify this to suit your needs such that the `colnames` says, for example, `4 Cylinder (Automatic)` `6 Cylinder (Automatic)` etc.

Comment: so thanks- the resulting function is nice and simple. But I don't see how to scale it up and add more grouping variables?

Comment: I missed that part. It can be done relatively simple! Ill update my answer when I get to the office!

Comment: The answer is updated - I guess it is about time I clean it up a bit!

Answer (score 3):

Outside `dplyr`, you could use the [`tables` package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tables/vignettes/tables.pdf) which allows to create summary statistics out of a table formula:

```
library(tables)

vars <- c("V1","V2")
vars <- paste(vars, collapse="+")

table <- as.formula(paste("(group = factor(Group)) ~ (", vars ,")*(mean+sd)"))
table
# (group = factor(Group)) ~ (V1 + V2) * (mean + sd)

tables::tabular(table, data = data)
#       V1              V2            
# group mean     sd     mean    sd    
# 1     -0.15759 0.9771  0.1405 1.0697
# 2      0.05084 0.9039 -0.1470 0.9949
```

Answer (score 3):

Slight variation of your original code, you could use `across()` more simply/flexibly if you  specify you don't want the ID (or the already-grouped Group) column, but rather everything else:

```
data %>%
  group_by(Group) %>%
  summarize(across(-ID, .fns = list(Mean = mean, SD = sd), .names = "{.col}_{.fn}"))

# A tibble: 2 x 5
  Group V1_Mean V1_SD V2_Mean V2_SD
  <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>
1     1 -0.0167 0.979   0.145  1.02
2     2  0.119  1.11   -0.277  1.05
```

EDIT:
If you want to create your (first) goal exactly, you can use the `gt` package to make an html table with column spanners:

```
data %>%
  group_by(Group) %>%
  summarize(across(-ID, .fns = list(Mean = mean, SD = sd), .names = "{.col}_{.fn}")) %>%
  gt::gt() %>%
  gt::tab_spanner_delim("_") %>%
  gt::fmt_number(-Group, decimals = 2)
```

[image]

As to your other question, you could alternately do something like this to get the combined & transposed variation:

```
data %>%
  group_by(Group) %>%
  summarize(across(-ID, .fns = ~paste0(
    sprintf("%.2f", mean(.x)),
    sprintf(" (%.2f)", sd(.x))))) %>%
  t() %>%
  as.data.frame() 


               V1           V2
Group            1            2
V1    -0.02 (0.98)  0.12 (1.11)
V2     0.15 (1.02) -0.28 (1.05)
```

Answer (score 2):

One way to make a nice summary table is to use a package called `gtsummary` (note I am a co-author on this package just as an FYI). Below I am just formatting the data a little bit in `data2` and dropping the `ID` variable. Then it is a two line call to gtsummary to summarize your data. The by statement is what stratifies the table, and in the statistics input I am simply telling to show the mean and sd, by default gtsummary will show median q1-q3. This table can be rendered in all markdown options (word, pdf, html).

```
library(dplyr)
library(gtsummary)
data <- as.data.frame(cbind(1:100, sample(1:2), rnorm(100), rnorm(100)))
names(data) <- c("ID", "Group", "V1", "V2")

data2 <- data %>% 
          mutate(Group = ifelse(Group == 1, "Group Var1","Group Var2")) %>%
          select(-ID)

tbl_summary(data2, by = Group,
            statistic = all_continuous()~ "{mean} ({sd})")
```

[image: outputtable]

If you want more than one strata but do not want to use `tbl_strata` you can combine two variables into one column and use that in the by statement. You can `unite()` as many variables as you want (although maybe not reccomended)

```
trial %>%
  tidyr::unite(col = "trt_grade", trt, grade, sep = ", ") %>% 
    select(age, marker,stage,trt_grade) %>%
    tbl_summary(by = c(trt_grade))
```

Comment: thanks. I like this table as well and the base code for `tbl_summary` is pretty simple. But it's not easy to scale up with multiple grouping variables and `tbl_strata()` gets complicated quickly. Am I missing something?

Comment: @socialresearcher if you want to scale up with out using `tbl_strata()` you can paste variables together or unite them using tidyr and then use that new variable in the by statement. I edited my answer to a newer solution.

Answer (score 1):

A `data.table` option

```
dcast(
  setDT(data)[,
    c(
      .(Meas = c("M", "Sd")),
      lapply(.SD, function(x) c(mean(x), sd(x)))
    ),
    Group,
    .SDcols = patterns("V\\d")
  ], Group ~ Meas,
  value.var = c("V1", "V2")
)
```

gives

```
   Group       V1_M    V1_Sd        V2_M     V2_Sd
1:     1 -0.2392583 1.097343 -0.08048455 0.7851212
2:     2  0.1059716 1.011769 -0.23356373 0.9927975
```

Comment: I root for you in this contest :)

Comment: @AnoushiravanR Thank you man! I am here just for fun :P

Answer (score 1):

You can also use base R:

```
# using do.call to make the result a data.frame
do.call(
       data.frame
        # here you aggregate for all the functions you need
      ,(aggregate(. ~ Group, data = data[,-1], FUN = function(x) c(mn = mean(x), sd = sd(x))))
       )
```

This leads to something like this:

```
 Group      V1.mn    V1.sd      V2.mn    V2.sd
1     1  0.1239868 1.008214 0.07215481 1.026059
2     2 -0.2324611 1.048230 0.11348897 1.071467
```

If you want a fancier table, `kableExtra` could really help. Note, the `%>%` should be imported also in `kableExtra`, but in case, from R 4.1 you can use `|>` instead of it:

```
library(kableExtra)
# data manipulation as above, note the [,-1] to remove the Group column
do.call(
        data.frame
       ,(aggregate(. ~ Group, data = data[,-1], FUN = function(x) c(mn = mean(x), sd = sd(x)))))[,-1] %>%
  # here you define as a kable, and give the names you want to columns
  kbl(col.names = rep(c('mean','sd'),2)  ) %>%
  # some formatting
  kable_paper() %>%
  # adding the first header
  add_header_above(c( "Group 1" = 2, "Group 2" = 2)) %>%
  # another header if you need it
  add_header_above(c( "Big group" = 4))
```

[image]

And you can find [much more](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/kableExtra/vignettes/awesome_table_in_html.html) to make great tables.

---

In case, you can also try something like this:

```
do.call(data.frame,
        aggregate(. ~ Group, data = data[,-1], FUN = function(x) paste0(round(mean(x),2),' (', round(sd(x),2),')'))
        ) %>%
 kbl() %>%
 kable_paper()
```

That leads to:
[image]

Comment: Such great package `kableExtra` is. Just never had the chance to explore its ins and outs.

Comment: @Anoushiravan R , you're right, I think the same things!