# Summarising multiple variables without iteration

Tags: r, tidyverse

Consider this `data` that needs the `summary` measures `mean` and `sd` on multiple variables,

```
# Create grouping var; ####
mtcars <- mtcars %>% mutate(
        am = case_when(
                am == 0 ~ "Automatic",
                TRUE ~ "Manual"
        )
)
```

With the following custom `function` and `purrr`, I can create a `baseline table`,

```
# Summarising function; ####
sum_foo <- function(data, var) {
        
        data %>% 
                group_by(am) %>% 
                summarise(
                        mean = mean( !!sym(var) , na.rm = TRUE),
                        sd   = sd( !!sym(var) , na.rm = TRUE)
                ) %>% 
                mutate(across(where(is.double), round, 2)) %>%  
                group_by(am) %>% 
                transmute(
                        value = paste(mean, "(±", sd, ")", sep = ""),
                        variable = var
                ) %>%
                pivot_wider(
                        names_from = "am"
                )
        
        
}


# Execute Function; ####
sum_variables <- c("mpg", "hp", "disp")


sum_variables %>% map(
        sum_foo,
        data = mtcars
) %>% reduce(
        bind_rows
)
```

Which gives the following `output`,

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  variable Automatic       Manual        
  <chr>    <chr>           <chr>         
1 mpg      17.15(±3.83)    24.39(±6.17)  
2 hp       160.26(±53.91)  126.85(±84.06)
3 disp     290.38(±110.17) 143.53(±87.2)
```

I want to get the `output` without using `map` and `reduce`, ie. without iterating through the variables with `rowwise` or `map`.

I'm looking for an **alternative** `tidyverse`-solution!

Comment: map and reduce come from purrr which is part of the tidyverse, so how is this not a tidy solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe you could use this solution:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(tibble)

sum_variables %>%
  enframe() %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(output = list(sum_foo(mtcars, value))) %>%
  select(output) %>%
  unnest(cols = output)

# A tibble: 3 x 3
  variable Automatic       Manual        
  <chr>    <chr>           <chr>         
1 mpg      17.15(±3.83)    24.39(±6.17)  
2 hp       160.26(±53.91)  126.85(±84.06)
3 disp     290.38(±110.17) 143.53(±87.2)
```

**Updated**
Or you could even modify your function in the following way:

```
sum_foo2 <- function(data, var) {
  data %>% 
    group_by(am) %>% 
    summarise(across(all_of(var), list(Mean = mean, sd = sd))) %>% 
    mutate(across(where(is.double), round, 2)) %>%  
    group_by(am) %>%
    summarise(across(ends_with("Mean"), ~ paste(.x, "(±", get(gsub("_Mean", "_sd", cur_column())), ")", sep = ""))) %>%
    pivot_longer(!am, names_to = "Mean", values_to = "Val") %>%
    pivot_wider(names_from = "am", values_from = "Val")
}

sum_foo2(mtcars, sum_variables)

# A tibble: 3 x 3
  Mean      Automatic       Manual        
  <chr>     <chr>           <chr>         
1 mpg_Mean  17.15(±3.83)    24.39(±6.17)  
2 hp_Mean   160.26(±53.91)  126.85(±84.06)
3 disp_Mean 290.38(±110.17) 143.53(±87.2)
```

If I am to trim the function above into a more concise version:

```
sum_foo2 <- function(data, var) {
  data %>%
    group_by(am) %>%
    summarise(across(all_of(var), ~ paste0(round(mean(.x), 2), "(±", round(sd(.x), 2), ")"))) %>%
    pivot_longer(!am, names_to = "Mean", values_to = "Val") %>%
    pivot_wider(names_from = "am", values_from = "Val")
}

sum_foo2(mtcars, sum_variables)
```

Comment: This is an awesome `tidyverse` only solution. Im testing your answer currently, and modified it a bit `summarise(across(all_of(sum_variables),~ paste0(mean(.) %>% round(2), "(±", sd(.) %>% round(2), ")") ))`. 


Without using the custom `function`. Can you elaborate on the use of `get` and `gsub` here, vs how I modified it?

Comment: You're welcome, glad it helped. Before the last `summarize` function we have 6 variables (actually 7 with `am`) where 3 of them are `Mean` suffixed and 3 other are `sd` suffixed. Since the naming is almost the same I first chose those who `ends_with` `Mean` for `.cols` argument of `across` and then swap them with those that are suffixed by `sd` in a way that I modify the name by replacing `_Mean` with `gsub` and then get the value with `get` function. Here `cur_column` is actually referring to those initial choices which are `Mean` suffixed.

Comment: You know without using `get` the output of `gsub` would only be a character vector of length 3 containing `mpg_sd` etc... and we use `get` to find the variable corresponding to this name in the context of our data set.

Comment: What other modifications you would like to apply on this?

Comment: Actually there is no other modification, other than what I wrote in this section. :-)

Comment: Oh I didn't notice the parentheses, I edited that part. If I'm not mistaken you would like to `round` all the outputs to 2 digits but they are actually rounded to 2 digits.

Comment: @Anoushiravan R: This must have been hard for you my friend, but you did it without `map`! YEAH. :-)

Comment: @TarJae Hahaha yeah but I will only do it once in a season. Next time don't count on me.

Answer (score 4):

Without using the function that you wrote, which require an iteration, ie rowwise/map, You could simply do:

```
sum_variables <- c("mpg", "hp", "disp")
mtcars %>%
  group_by(am) %>%
  summarise(across(all_of(sum_variables),
        ~sprintf('%.2f(\u00B1%.2f)', mean(.x), sd(.x))), .groups = 'drop') %>%
  data.table::transpose(keep.names = 'variable', make.names = TRUE)

 variable       Automatic         Manual
1      mpg    17.15(±3.83)   24.39(±6.17)
2       hp  160.26(±53.91) 126.85(±84.06)
3     disp 290.38(±110.17) 143.53(±87.20)
```

Comment: Is there a `transpose` equivalent in `tidyverse` that does not include `pivot_*`? I like this solution.

Comment: @Serkan, you will have to use `column_to_rownames` then `t` then `as.data.frame` then `type_convert`

Comment: @Serkan you do not need `type_convert`  anyway. that is because everything ia character

Answer (score 3):

So: Please be gentile. My solution without using `map` and `reduce`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)

data %>% 
    group_by(am) %>% 
    summarise(across(c(mpg, hp, disp), list(mean = mean, sd = sd), .names = "{.col}_{.fn}")) %>% 
    pivot_longer (
        cols = 2:7,
        names_to = "variable",
        values_to = "values"
    ) %>% 
    pivot_wider(
        names_from = am,
        values_from = values
    ) %>% 
    mutate(variable = str_extract(variable, "[^_]*")) %>% 
    mutate(across(c(Automatic, Manual), lead, .names = "{.col}_{.fn}")) %>% 
    filter(row_number() %% 2 == 1) %>% 
    mutate(across(where(is.numeric), round, 2)) %>% 
    mutate(Automatic = paste0(Automatic,"(±",Automatic_1,")"), .keep="unused") %>% 
    mutate(Manual = paste0(Manual,"(±",Manual_1,")"), .keep="unused")
```

Output:

```
  variable Automatic       Manual        
  <chr>    <chr>           <chr>         
1 mpg      17.15(±3.83)    24.39(±6.17)  
2 hp       160.26(±53.91)  126.85(±84.06)
3 disp     290.38(±110.17) 143.53(±87.2)
```

Comment: This is actually way better than my first attempt on this! :-)

Answer (score 3):

With the formidable answers that I got, this is the final `tidyverse`-solution without iteration or `map` that were born,

```
mtcars %>% 
        group_by(am) %>% 
        summarise(
                across(
                        all_of(sum_variables),
                        ~ paste0(mean(.) %>% round(2), "(±", sd(.) %>% round(2), ")")
                        )
                ) %>% pivot_longer(
                        cols = -"am"
                ) %>% pivot_wider(
                        names_from = "am"
                )
```

Which gives the following `output`,

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  name  Automatic       Manual        
  <chr> <chr>           <chr>         
1 mpg   17.15(±3.83)    24.39(±6.17)  
2 hp    160.26(±53.91)  126.85(±84.06)
3 disp  290.38(±110.17) 143.53(±87.2)
```

Comment: Yes I think we could emulate `data.table::transpose` with one `pivot_longer` followed by a `pivot_wider` in such cases.