# Adding differences to a summary-table created without iteration

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

Based on my first question found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68521013/summarising-multiple-variables-without-iteration) about creating a summary table without iteration, ie. without using `map`, I made the following algorithm based on the formidable answers,

```
library(tidyverse)

sum_variables <- c("mpg", "hp", "disp")

# Create grouping var; ####
mtcars <- mtcars %>% mutate(
        am_factor = case_when(
                am == 0 ~ "Automatic",
                TRUE ~ "Manual"
        )
)

# Create summary table; ####
mtcars %>% 
        group_by(am_factor) %>% 
        summarise(
                across(
                        all_of(sum_variables),
                        ~ paste0(mean(.) %>% round(2), "(±", sd(.) %>% round(2), ")")
                )
        ) %>% pivot_longer(
                cols = -"am_factor"
        ) %>% pivot_wider(
                names_from = "am_factor"
        )
```

Which gives me the following `output`,

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  name  Automatic       Manual        
  <chr> <chr>           <chr>         
1 mpg   17.15(±3.83)    24.39(±6.17)  
2 hp    160.26(±53.91)  126.85(±84.06)
3 disp  290.38(±110.17) 143.53(±87.2)
```

Using `paste0` here has the benefit of reducing the amount of codes needed in the algorithm, but complicates further additions to table. If I, for example, want to add `differences` to this table, my current solution is the following,

```
mtcars %>% 
        group_by(am_factor) %>% 
        summarise(
                across(
                        all_of(sum_variables),
                        ~ paste0(mean(.) %>% round(2), "(±", sd(.) %>% round(2), ")")
                )
        ) %>% pivot_longer(
                cols = -"am_factor"
        ) %>% pivot_wider(
                names_from = "am_factor"
        ) %>% mutate(
                difference = str_extract(Automatic, "[:digit:].?[:digit:]") %>% as.numeric() - 
                        str_extract(Manual, "[:digit:].?[:digit:]") %>% as.numeric()
        )
```

Which gives the desired `output`,

```
# A tibble: 3 × 4
  name  Automatic       Manual         difference
  <chr> <chr>           <chr>               <dbl>
1 mpg   17.15(±3.83)    24.39(±6.17)           -7
2 hp    160.26(±53.91)  126.85(±84.06)         34
3 disp  290.38(±110.17) 143.53(±87.2)         147
```

Although it works, it defeats the purpose of making a simple algorithm for the purpose.

---

How do I create a `summary` of my `data` in a simple manner? It has to be a `tidyverse`-solution, preferably without iteration.

Answer (score 0):

This is not necessarily simpler or shorter but I would prefer to do the mathematical calculations on numbers directly rather than extracting them from strings.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

mtcars %>%
  group_by(am_factor) %>%
  summarise(across(all_of(sum_variables), list(mean = mean, 
            sd = ~sprintf('%.2f (± %.2f)', mean(.), sd(.))))) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -am_factor, 
               names_to = c('measure', '.value'), 
               names_sep = '_') %>%
  group_by(measure) %>%
  mutate(difference = -diff(mean)) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  select(-mean) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = am_factor, values_from = sd) 

#  measure difference Automatic         Manual          
#  <chr>        <dbl> <chr>             <chr>           
#1 mpg          -7.24 17.15 (± 3.83)    24.39 (± 6.17)  
#2 hp           33.4  160.26 (± 53.91)  126.85 (± 84.06)
#3 disp        147.   290.38 (± 110.17) 143.53 (± 87.20)
```