# Summary of DF as matrix

Tags: r, summary

I have been searching for quite a while now but couldn't really find a simple way. 
I have a df consisting of numerical values only and I want to Create a summary matrix out of my df.

```
DF
V1   V2   V3   V4   V5  ...
x1   y1   z1   1    c1  
x2   NA   z2   0    c2
x3   y3   z3   1    NA
...
```

V4 is originally a TRUE/FALSE variable tranformed into numerical variable which should usually work.
I want to obtain the following:

```
    N   Mean  SD  Min  1st  Median  3rd  Max
V1
V2 
V3
V4
V5
...
```

with the according values for N, Mean, SD, Min, 1st, Median, 3rd, Max.
I have tried the simple 
`as.data.frame(summary(DF))`
I have tried stargazer which doesn't work for some reason ( I am guessing because I have binal variables)

```
stargazer(DF, type= "html", nobs = TRUE, type="html", mean.sd = TRUE, median = TRUE, iqr = TRUE,
+           digits=2, align=T)
```

and I read something about qwraps2_summary_table. But they all seem to give a different "design" of table than what I am looking for.

I know I can also run a loop like:

```
for(i in (1:length(DF)){
sum$N<-(????)
sum$Mean<-mean(DF[i])
....}
```

But this is not the nicest solution.
Any tipps? Thank you!

Here a part of my dataset

```
structure(list(Year = c(2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 
2018, 2018, 2011), Occurences = c(9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 2L, 9L), Balance = c(-1.14, 1.05, -1.06, 1.01, 1.01, 1.01, 
-1.09, -1, -1.04, -1.03), Withdrawal = c(43200, 41080, 43400, 
43183, 42600, 42100, 45900, 46000, 3892008, 48374), Verification_SA = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 1, 1, NA, 1, 1, NA), Classification_num = c(NA, NA, 
NA, NA, 3, 2, NA, 4, 4, NA), Interaction_Verification_Classification = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 3, 2, NA, 4, 4, NA), KnowledgeSources = c(1, 1, 1, 
0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0), KnowledgeDischarge = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 0), Scarcity_watershed = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_
), Scarcity_country = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 3.35, 
NA), Knowledge_Watershed = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Knowledge_Facilities = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1), Importance_num = c(NA, NA, NA, 3, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 5, NA), DetrimentalImpacts_num = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Responsibility_num = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 
3, 1)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

Comment: Hi antonia, it will be much easier to help if you provide a sample of your data in the form of the output of the `dput()` function. Consider editing your post to include either all or a portion of `DF` with `dput(DF)` or `dput(DF[1:10,])`.

Comment: yes of course thank you!

Comment: There should be some ideas to help you out in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34594641/5325862) and possibly [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30520350/5325862)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If someone finds this question later, building off @camille's suggestion to check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34594641). Here is one approach that is simple, although it does not provide the number of `NA`s.

```
library(psych)
my_summary <- do.call(rbind,lapply(DF,psych::describe,quant=c(0.25,0.75)))
my_summary
#                                        vars  n      mean         sd   median  trimmed     mad      min        max      range  skew kurtosis        se    Q0.25    Q0.75
#Year                                       1 10   2014.50       2.72  2014.50  2014.50    3.71  2011.00    2018.00       7.00  0.00    -1.74      0.86  2012.25  2016.75
#Occurences                                 1 10      8.30       2.21     9.00     9.00    0.00     2.00       9.00       7.00 -2.28     3.57      0.70     9.00     9.00
#Balance                                    1 10     -0.23       1.07    -1.02    -0.27    0.15    -1.14       1.05       2.19  0.35    -2.05      0.34    -1.06     1.01
#Withdrawal                                 1 10 428784.50 1216854.64 43300.00 44344.62 2535.25 41080.00 3892008.00 3850928.00  2.28     3.57 384803.22 42745.75 45975.00
#Verification_SA                            1  4      1.00       0.00     1.00     1.00    0.00     1.00       1.00       0.00   NaN      NaN      0.00     1.00     1.00
#Classification_num                         1  4      3.25       0.96     3.50     3.25    0.74     2.00       4.00       2.00 -0.32    -2.08      0.48     2.75     4.00
...
```

Here is my original solution, using `data.table`.

```
library(data.table)
my_summary <- rbindlist(lapply(DF, function(x){
  as.data.frame(t(c(
    summary(x),
    SD = sd(x,na.rm=TRUE),
    N = sum(!is.na(x)))))
  })
  , fill = TRUE, use.names = TRUE,idcol="Variable")
my_summary
#                                   Variable     Min.   1st Qu.    Median          Mean  3rd Qu.       Max.           SD  N NA's
# 1:                                    Year  2011.00  2012.250  2014.500   2014.500000  2016.75    2018.00 2.718251e+00 10   NA
# 2:                              Occurences     2.00     9.000     9.000      8.300000     9.00       9.00 2.213594e+00 10   NA
# 3:                                 Balance    -1.14    -1.055    -1.015     -0.228000     1.01       1.05 1.074800e+00 10   NA
# 4:                              Withdrawal 41080.00 42745.750 43300.000 428784.500000 45975.00 3892008.00 1.216855e+06 10   NA
# 5:                         Verification_SA     1.00     1.000     1.000      1.000000     1.00       1.00 0.000000e+00  4    6
# 6:                      Classification_num     2.00     2.750     3.500      3.250000     4.00       4.00 9.574271e-01  4    6
```

Comment: I was about to post the same. I find an aesthetic alternative is to transpose this (by using `do.call(cbind, ...)` instead). Since columns tend to be formatted similarly based on numeric scale (esp with `tibble`s), I find having numbers of the same scale in a column to be preferential. I offer this solely as a constructive alternative.

Comment: (Though I would change your variable name away from a base R function. :-)

Comment: @Ian Campbell any idea what this error means?
`Error in is.data.frame(x) : 
  (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'`
its what I get when trying to add sd

Comment: Did you notice that this output suggests that `Withdrawal` (for example) has 41080 `NA` values in a 10-row frame? (Yes, this is just value recycling, but ... it's an issue nonetheless.)

Comment: @IanCampbell the SD thing works! But as r2evans said, something is up with the NA's...

Comment: thank you! Any way to add to that table the N for example by `N = is.na(x)==F`?

Answer (score 3):

To build on Ian Campbell's answer one should not fear to build a summary function when the need arises.

```
summaryfn <- function(x){
c(min(x),
quantile(x,0.25,na.rm=TRUE),
quantile(x,0.5,na.rm=TRUE),
mean(x,na.rm=TRUE),
sd(x, na.rm=TRUE),
quantile(x,0.75,na.rm=TRUE),
max(x,na.rm=TRUE),
sum(is.na(x)))

}

res <-   do.call(rbind,lapply(df,summaryfn))
colnames(res) <- c("Min","Q1","Med","Mean","Sd","Q3","Max","NAs")



## > res
##                                              Min        Q1       Med          Mean           Sd       Q3        Max NAs
## Year                                     2011.00  2012.250  2014.500   2014.500000 2.718251e+00  2016.75    2018.00   0
## Occurences                                  2.00     9.000     9.000      8.300000 2.213594e+00     9.00       9.00   0
## Balance                                    -1.14    -1.055    -1.015     -0.228000 1.074800e+00     1.01       1.05   0
## Withdrawal                              41080.00 42745.750 43300.000 428784.500000 1.216855e+06 45975.00 3892008.00   0
## Verification_SA                               NA     1.000     1.000      1.000000 0.000000e+00     1.00       1.00   6
## Classification_num                            NA     2.750     3.500      3.250000 9.574271e-01     4.00       4.00   6
## Interaction_Verification_Classification       NA     2.750     3.500      3.250000 9.574271e-01     4.00       4.00   6
## KnowledgeSources                            0.00     1.000     1.000      0.800000 4.216370e-01     1.00       1.00   0
## KnowledgeDischarge                          0.00     0.000     0.000      0.400000 5.163978e-01     1.00       1.00   0
## Scarcity_watershed                            NA        NA        NA           NaN           NA       NA       -Inf  10
## Scarcity_country                              NA     3.350     3.350      3.350000           NA     3.35       3.35   9
## Knowledge_Watershed                         0.00     0.000     0.000      0.000000 0.000000e+00     0.00       0.00   0
## Knowledge_Facilities                        0.00     0.000     0.000      0.200000 4.216370e-01     0.00       1.00   0
## Importance_num                                NA     3.000     3.000      3.333333 8.164966e-01     3.00       5.00   4
## DetrimentalImpacts_num                      0.00     0.000     0.000      0.100000 3.162278e-01     0.00       1.00   0
## Responsibility_num                          1.00     1.000     2.000      1.800000 7.888106e-01     2.00       3.00   0

## > str(res)
##  num [1:16, 1:8] 2011 2 -1.14 41080 NA ...
##  - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
##   ..$ : chr [1:16] "Year" "Occurences" "Balance" "Withdrawal" ...
##   ..$ : chr [1:8] "Min" "Q1" "Med" "Mean" ...
```

although I the `stargazer` is a good choice in many cases, I would recommend `xtable` for its flexibility.

```
print(xtable(res),type="html")
```

Comment: So true, I really got stuck in the `base::summary` mindset.

Comment: @DJJ this doesn't work either unfortunately for some reason the resutl is a "List of 112"
I also tried to add `sd(x, na.rm=TRUE)`
But even without that it didn't work

Comment: @antonina I see your concern. Yes I agree with you it was a matrix structured as a list. May be now it's better

Answer (score 0):

We can use `map` to loop over the `DF`, get the `summary` statistics, convert it to a `data.frame`, create. the 'SD' and 'N' columns in `tibble` to create a single data.frame output with suffix (`_dfr` in `map`)

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
map_dfr(DF, ~  tibble(SD = sd(.x, na.rm = TRUE), 
   N = sum(!is.na(.x)),  as.data.frame.list(base::summary(.x))),
     .id = 'Variable')
# A tibble: 16 x 10
#           SD     N     Min. X1st.Qu.   Median      Mean X3rd.Qu.     Max.  NA.s Variable                
# *      <dbl> <int>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl> <chr>                   
# 1    2.72e+0    10  2011     2012.    2014.     2.01e+3  2017.     2.02e3    NA Year                    
# 2    2.21e+0    10     2        9        9      8.30e+0     9      9.00e0    NA Occurences              
# 3    1.07e+0    10    -1.14    -1.06    -1.02  -2.28e-1     1.01   1.05e0    NA Balance                 
# 4    1.22e+6    10 41080    42746.   43300      4.29e+5 45975      3.89e6    NA Withdrawal              
# 5    0.          4     1        1        1      1.00e+0     1      1.00e0     6 Verification_SA         
# 6    9.57e-1     4     2        2.75     3.5    3.25e+0     4      4.00e0     6 Classification_num      
# 7    9.57e-1     4     2        2.75     3.5    3.25e+0     4      4.00e0     6 Interaction_Verificatio…
# 8    4.22e-1    10     0        1        1      8.00e-1     1      1.00e0    NA KnowledgeSources        
# 9    5.16e-1    10     0        0        0      4.00e-1     1      1.00e0    NA KnowledgeDischarge      
#10   NA           0    NA       NA       NA    NaN          NA     NA         10 Scarcity_watershed      
#11   NA           1     3.35     3.35     3.35   3.35e+0     3.35   3.35e0     9 Scarcity_country        
#12    0.         10     0        0        0      0.          0      0.        NA Knowledge_Watershed     
#13    4.22e-1    10     0        0        0      2.00e-1     0      1.00e0    NA Knowledge_Facilities    
#14    8.16e-1     6     3        3        3      3.33e+0     3      5.00e0     4 Importance_num          
#15    3.16e-1    10     0        0        0      1.00e-1     0      1.00e0    NA DetrimentalImpacts_num  
#16    7.89e-1    10     1        1        2      1.80e+0     2      3.00e0    NA Responsibility_num
```

Comment: to me it returns just NA

Comment: @akrun now i get the following error `Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : 
  ònly for data frame, with only numeric variables`
when trying `DF<-as.numeric(DF)` I get the following error `Error: (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'`

Comment: FYI, this fails for me with `purrr-0.3.3`, R-3.5.3, win10.

Comment: @IanCampbell, that's a good thought. For me, though, I cannot find one instance of `summary` from all of my installed packages that could be a candidate (all have different classes, so S3 should not have mis-used them). It's entirely likely I'm missing packages, and I make no assumptions about somebody else's available packages. Good thought, would be curious if akrun finds something in his current environment that might be triggering a mask.

Comment: @r2evans I changed the code, and it should work for you now because the `summary` output is converted to `data.frame`

Comment: @akrun thank you for the suggested update. Unfortunately it still doesn't work and I get the error `Error in dim(data) <- dim : invalid first argument`
I feel like something is wrong with my df but it worked with Ian Campbells answer so I am happy about that!

Comment: It is not any function masking `base` because ` ?summary` returns only the `base` help

Comment: @r2evans I also have `packageVersion('purrr')#
[1] ‘0.3.3’`, but my `R` versioin is `R 3.6.2` on a mac

Comment: I have `tibble-2.1.3` (I know 3.0.0 is available), it seems like that might be a candidate.

Comment: @r2evans i have `packageVersion('tibble')#
[1] ‘2.99.99.9014’`

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not in an easy position (nor do I assume you are) to uproot my whole library to install a (for me, untested) new version of `tibble`. There are enough *breaking changes* listed in the package [`NEWS`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tibble/news/news.html) (not to mention the major change implied by its semantic versioning) that I'm hesitant to make the leap.

Comment: @r2evans I would usually spin up a docker container and check for  any new cases